# Tool for finding third party vulnerabilities

Tags: security

Does anyone know of a `.dll` scanner that searches for known vulnerabilities?

At work, we have a project which uses Nuget packages, and other .dll dependencies. I know there are databases of known vulnerabilities [[1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27757/is-there-a-tool-for-finding-third-party-vulnerabilities)](https://cve.mitre.org/index.html)[[2](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/current-activity), but does anyone know of a tool that will scan a build output folder for `.dll` names/versions/etc. to spot `.dll`s with known vulnerabilities?

The goal will be to have this tool run periodically, and alert me if a vulnerability is found in our of our dependencies so that we can update it. Always staying up to date is a testing burden (still working on comprehensive automated testing!) so not updating our dependencies more than we have to is very necessary still for us.

Other information about the environment:

- C# project/solution with VS 2015 Update 1
- Does not have to be open source, and if it's pricey the business can probably afford it.

EDIT: I did not know that software recommendations were not appropriate for this site.  I'm leaving it open on here (even though it will probably be closed) so that those who upvoted the post can find it again.

I re-posted the question on the [appropriate stackexchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) [[here]](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27757/is-there-a-tool-for-finding-third-party-vulnerabilities)

Comment: If this is a bad question for this site, is there a better stackexchange site for it?

Comment: [OWASP Dependency Check](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check) is free and open source, and works for .Net projects.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I looked at that one, but the results are just a search query of the OWASP vulnerability database based on the name of the .dll.  For instance, if the dll is named EntitySqlServerTools.dll (I made that up) then all the sql vulnerabilities show up in that result list, and make the EntitySqlServerTools.dll a "high" risk of vulnerability.  With a lot of .dlls, this list takes hardly less time to sift through than doing the query and searching manually.

Comment: To be honest I have seen similar dependency tools for what you are looking for. But they end up just being a interface for DBs like OSWASP Depedency Check. And do no more than comparing the extension and version. This DB has such an interface. You can integrate it as CLI, CI, or other build tools to search your dependency folder and do the queries for you. https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/

Comment: @BradMetcalf thanks for that link, it looks very useful and I'll give it a shot

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll post there and delete this one as soon as I get to a computer (on my phone now)

Comment: @NeilSmithline Would you recommend that I delete it, or wait for it to get closed for bookkeeping purposes?  It seems that 2 people have upvoted it (and 2 down) so I'm not sure how I feel about deleting it if 2 people liked it (and may check back on it.)

Comment: I suggest that you leave it open. Even if it gets closed you may get an answer beforehand. You may also try this site's [associated chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz). The rules are pretty loose there and maybe you'll get lucky.